# NameError: uninitialized constant in controller while rspec controller testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

Controller code

```
before_action :verify_request

def verify_request
  unless request.headers['Authorization'].present? && request.headers['Authorization'] == APIKEY["authorization_key"]
    render json: { message: "UnAuthorize Request" }, status: 401
  end
end
```

Rspec code:

```
describe "GET #index" do
  it "returns 400 (empty query parameter)" do
    request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "testing123"
    get :index
    expect(response).to have_http_status(400)
  end
end
```

Issue i face is that while rspec testing, environment variables are not accessible in controller and tests are failing. How do i fix that?

Note: I defined `authorization_key` in config/authorization.yml for all environments and its working in dev mode but not in testing.

Error I get is:

```
Failure/Error: unless request.headers['Authorization'].present? && request.headers['Authorization'] == APIKEY["authorization_key"]

 NameError:
   uninitialized constant V1::LocationController::APIKEY
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the stack trace of error?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh i update question

Comment: @HaseebAhmad where in the application do you define `APIKEY`? Please show that.

Comment: @maxpleaner in config/initializers/app_config.rb

Comment: @JagdeepSingh any solution?

Comment: @HaseebAhmad please show the content of the file not just the name of the file ...

Answer (score 1):

Did you included `require 'rails_helper'` into your `CONTROLLER-NAME_controller_spec.rb`

Comment: require 'rails_helper'